# adding content problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I've got some trouble trying to add content in a page.

```
<body>      
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>exercizeI</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>exercizeII</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>........</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>........</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

So I'be tried to use that piece of code and it didn't work

```
var table1='<table>..some content..</table>}';
$('#nav li a:eq(1)').click(function (){$('#content').innerHTML='habarlaaaa';});
```

then tried this one

```
function press(){
 var but = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li')[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 var table1='<table>..some content..</table>}';
 var content = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementById('content');
 but.onclick=function(){content.innerHTML=table1};
};
```

..and it became even worse by giving me:


Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementById'


error

Why is this happening?

BR, Stephan

Comment: I removed the references to [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/AJAX), since the question doesn't actually relate to AJAX specifically.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to do `getElementById().getElementById()`. `Id`-s are (should be) unique within the html document, so you only need one `getElementById` call (it is a method of `document` anyway).

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery you can use the html() function like this:

```
 $('#nav li a:eq(1)').click(function (){$('#content').html(table1);});
```

Answer (score 2):

To add data inside the content div:

```
$('#content').append("data");
```

The reason why your second try fails is because you are applying getElementById() to the result of the previous "getElementById()".

Answer (score 1):

In your first Javascript code you were mixing concepts of DOM methods and jQuery code. Please try the following code

```
$('#nav li a:eq(1)').click(function (){$('#content').eq(0).html('habarlaaaa');});
```

the difference is that instead of

```
$('#content').innerHTML = '......';
```

You should have used

```
.eq(0).html('habarlaaaa')
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Vincent, the reasoning is that when you use the jQuery function, `$`, you don't get a DOM element, but rather you get a jQuery object representing what you've selected.  There are a couple ways of doing this, one of which @vincent-ramdhanie has already mentioned.  If you want to get at the actual DOM element, you can do either this:

```
$('#content')[0].innerHTML='habarlaaaa';
```

or this:

```
$('#content').get(0).innerHTML='habarlaaaa';
```

remember: `innerHTML` is a property of a DOM element, not a jQuery object.